# order affecting the probability

Tags: probability

There are $9$ balls - $4$ red, $3$ white and $2$ green balls in a bag. Total $4$ balls are taken out of that bag without replacement with the condition that exactly $2$ are red and $2$ are non-red. IMO, probability should be:

$$(4/9)*(3/8)*(5/7)*(4/6)$$

If I had taken out non-red balls for the first two times, the probability would've been:

$$(5/9)*(4/8)*(4/7)*(3/6)$$

Finally we will have only one sets of balls and probability is same irrespective of the order in which they are drawn - so why do we need to consider order?

Comment: These two expressions produce the same result. Did you mean to ask why order doesn't affect the probability?

Comment: @ElliotYu No, the answer to the question should be: $(4C2*5C2)/9C4$ - it takes order in which the balls are drawn into account. Hence I wanted to know how does the order affects the probability.

Answer (score 1):

Beginners often get puzzled/err on such problems.

Here no specific order has been given, so we need to consider **all** possible orders if we use the direct multiplication route to compute probability, thus the correct answer using the direct multiplication method should be

$(4/9)*(3/8)*(5/7)*(4/6)\times \frac{4!}{2!2!}$

Alternatively, it can be more simply computed as $\binom42\binom52 /\binom94$

Comment: Why all routes needs to be considered as the final outcome will have 2 red balls and 2 non-red balls irrespective of the route taken?

Comment: Had the order been specified as, say, two red followed by two non-red, then (4/9)*(3/8)*(5/7)*(4/6) would be correct. But as the order has **not** been specified, we have to consider **all** possible orders,  eg RRNN, RNRN , NRNR, ... etc  The question in effect asks for the probability of two reds, two non-reds in **all possible** orders.

Comment: sorry I still didn't get it!

Comment: If I ask you what is the probability that two reds and two non-reds are drawn in all possible orders, what is your answer ? Will it not be $P(RRNN) +P(RNRN) + P(RNNR) + P(NRRN) + P(NRNR) + P(NNRR) ?$ The question is **asking** for this by not specifying any particular order.

Comment: What I am trying to understand is the final outcome is $2$ red and $2$ non-red balls and only the outcome should matter here.

Comment: Look, $\binom 42\binom52/ \binom54$ gives the final outcome of two red, two non-red, doesn't it ? Ponder how to get the same answer when using the direct multiplication method !